# Creating a function (equation) based on different variable scores that loops through multiple columns

Tags: r, for-loop, multiple-columns, equation

I would like to run this equation based on different variable scores in multiple columns simultaneously:

#1scores/(#1scores+#2scores+#0scores)

If my DF looks like this

```
20   21   22     
1    NA   2
1    1    0
NA   2    0
NA   0    NA
0    NA   1
2    1    1
```

So for  the column named 20 (or position one, with 21 being position two etc) I would calculate 2/4 given the above equation.

But I want to calculate this for each column at the same time (let's say there are 100 columns), and each column has a varying number of 1, 2 and 0 scores and NA's (thus the NA's appear in different positions and quantities). I don't want to consider the NA's in the first equation.

However, the second check I wanted to run, again on all columns simultaneously, was to see how many NAs were in each column.

I believe I should use a for loop, and understand them conceptually, but am unsure how to execute the code inside the loop to do what I want.

If anyone can assist, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I dont get the formula. How you calculate 2/4 for the column called `20` with values `c(1,1,NA,NA,0,2)` ?

Comment: because there are 2 "1" values, and 4 values "which count"-(1,1,0,2).

Thus in my equation, 2 "1" values are divided by 4 "values which count"

Sorry, I should add "number of 1 scores, number of 2scores" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 0, 1, 2 and `NA` are the only values in your dataframe you can do -

```
colMeans(df == 1, na.rm = TRUE)

# V1  V2  V3 
#0.5 0.5 0.4
```

If there are values other than those, you can specifically look for the values of interest.

```
colSums(df == 1, na.rm = TRUE)/colSums(df == 1 | df == 2 | df == 0, na.rm = TRUE)
```

for this dataset this will give the same output as above.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 2L), V2 = c(NA, 1L, 
2L, 0L, NA, 1L), V3 = c(2L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: No, I don't need the means, I need the accuracy, which those values reference, but I haven't explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Okay sorry. But I wanted the % of 1's (correct answers) using the equation #scoring1/(#scoring1+#scoring2+#scoring0) where 0's and2's are incorrect answers.

Comment: Yes, I just realised as I was reading it back! 

If I wanted to run the code on say columns 50-100 only in my DF, would it be something like colMeans(df [50:100] == 1, na.rm = TRUE)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `table` to count the scores and do the following:

```
calculateColumn <- function(columnValues) {
  scoreCounts <- table(columnValues)
  return(scoreCounts[["1"]]/sum(scoreCounts))
}
df <- data.frame(V1 = c(1,1,NA,NA,0,2), V2 = c(NA,1,2,0,NA,1),V3 = c(2,0,0,NA,1,1))

sapply(df,calculateColumn)
```

resulting in

```
V1  V2  V3 
0.5 0.5 0.4
```

Note: We assume that there are only 0,1,2 and NA in the dataframe, otherwise the `sum(table...)` would count too much in the denominator.

To count the `NA`s in each column, you can simply do

```
colSums(is.na(df))
```

Comment: There are other values in the DF, but not in the columns I want to run the equation on, which is actually #scoring1/(#scoring1+#scoring2+#scoring0).

So I want to run this equation on the values in the columns 1-100 and see the output.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `summarise` with `across` in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ mean(. == 1, na.rm = TRUE)))
#   V1  V2  V3
#1 0.5 0.5 0.4
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c(1L, 1L, NA, NA, 0L, 2L), V2 = c(NA, 1L, 
2L, 0L, NA, 1L), V3 = c(2L, 0L, 0L, NA, 1L, 1L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thanks , I have used the first answer as a solution but I will expand my knowledge with what you have suggested.